# How to install apxs in linux?

Tags: linux, apache-httpd

I want to install Apache extension tool in linux.

I tried following things:

1. `yum install httpd-devel`
2. `yum install apache2-dev`

All I got is no package available.

Comment: Insert into your question: 1) your linux distribution and version 2) the exact error message (copy-paste it).

Comment: ANSWER
To install `apxs` on Oracle Linux run:

```yum install httpd-devel```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are on `Centos` or `Rhel`,  and you do not have a repository configured. If you currently do not hold a [Red Hat Subscription](https://www.redhat.com/en/store/linux-platforms) and yet you need to enable EPEL ( Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux ) repository on your RHEL 7 you need to add an EPEL repo, you can do so by running the following commands.

This should add a repository to your system.

For **64 bit** `RHEL` and `Centos` systems:

```
cd /tmp
wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
ls *.rpm
sudo yum install epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

You should be able to see the repository using `yum repolist` under `epel/x86_64                                     Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64`

This works for both **Centos 7.xx and Rhel 7.xx**

Comment: To install `apxs` on Oracle Linux run:

```yum install httpd-devel```

Comment: @ragerdl's `yum install httpd-devel` also worked for me in Amazon Linux.

Comment: On a cpanel based CentOs setup, httpd-devel was blocked, but you can get it thru: `yum install ea-apache24-devel` as mentioned here: https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/install-httpd-devel.594631/